# Password_Hash no funcionan en mi login PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, login

Estoy haciendo un formulario de login y registro y utilizo password_hash para la encriptación de contraseñas, el problema es que al momento de loguearme no reconoce mi contraseña y me sale el error de "la contraseña es incorrecta" (un mensaje que establecí). En el formulario de registro no hay problemas, pero tal vez tiene que ver con el error que tengo.

Login.php

```
<?php
include 'connect/config.php';
session_start();
error_reporting(0);

if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
  header('Location: home');
}

if (isset($_POST["signin"])) {
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["password"]);

  $check_email = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'");

  if (mysqli_num_rows($check_email) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_email);
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row['id'];
    if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
        $msg[] = "Te has logeado exitosamente.";
    }
    header('Location: home');
    
  } else {
    $msg[] = "La contraseña o el correo electrónico son incorrectos.";
  }
}
?>
```

ahora bien, si cambio el `$check_email = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'");`   por   `$check_email = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE email='$email'");` puedo ingresar al home, pero con cualquier contraseña y no con la que me registré.

Registro.php

```
<?php

include 'connect/config.php';
session_start();
error_reporting(0);

if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    header("Location: home");
  }
if (isset($_POST["signup"])) {
    $full_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["signup_full_name"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["signup_email"]);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["signup_password"]);
    $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["signup_cpassword"]);
    $token = md5(rand());
  
    $check_email = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'"));
  
    if ($password !== $cpassword) {
      $msg[] = "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
    } elseif ($check_email > 0) {
      $msg[] = "El correo electrónico ya existe, pruebe con otro.";
    } else {
      $passHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, email, password, token, status) VALUES ('$full_name', '$email', '$passHash', '$token', '0')";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if ($result) {

        header('Location: login');

        $_POST["signup_full_name"] = "";
        $_POST["signup_email"] = "";
        $_POST["signup_password"] = "";
        $_POST["signup_cpassword"] = "";
        $msg[] = "Usuario registrado con éxito.";
      } else {
        $msg[] = "Registro de usuario fallido, inténtelo mas tarde.";
      }
    }
}
?>
```

espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Estás haciendo `SELECT id FROM users` al traer la fila de la BD. Si hicieras debug, verías que no tienes campo password pa comparar...

Comment: Crear consultas concatenando los parámetros en un string es una muy mala práctica. Estás expuesto a inyección SQL: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php

Answer (score 1):

Al crear un nuevo usuario estan guardando el password de forma correcta ya que se guarda encriptado en la base de datos. Sin embargo tienes dos fallos a la hora de logear el usuario:

En primer lugar estás intentando recuperar un usuario de base de datos buscando además de por usuario, por un password sin encriptar, lo que te va a dar siempre un resultado de 0. Deberías ejecutar un query que solo busque por usuario:

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'
```

Por otra parte cuando recuperas el usuario, aunque compreubas si la contraseña es correcta "dejas continuar" al usuario fuera de esta comprobación, es decir, deberías llevar al usuario a la Home dentro del "if" que comprueba que la contraseña es correcta.

```
if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
    $msg[] = "Te has logeado exitosamente.";
    header('Location: home');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar sha512 que ofrece mayor seguridad que MD5 y es uno de los hash más utilizados, para encriptar las contraseñas en el registro:

```
$password = $_POST['signup_password']);
$password = hash('sha512', $password);
```

En lugar de esto:

```
$passHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Y una vez que te vas a loguear:

```
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $password = hash('sha512', $password);
```

Adicionalmente no deberías concatenar tus parámetros en una cadena, por seguridad se recomiendan consultas preparadas y podrías sanitizar los datos